# How to get a value to Go code from a C callback function

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to incorporate a C library into my Go application. The interface to the C library uses a callback to handle logging. It ends up looking something like this:

```
/*
#include "clibrary/header.h"

void log_callback(const char * log)
{
  /* I'd like to get this log value to use in my Go code */
  fprintf(stderr, "Log is: %s\n", log);
}

/* Using this wrapper method so the callback can be added to
   the function call since it seems from my reading that 
   access to a C pointer to a function is difficult in CGO. 
*/    
int do_c_stuff_wrapper(Context * context)
{

  return do_c_stuff(context, log_callback)
}

*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

func DoCStuff() {

  c_context := C.init_context()
  ret := C.do_c_stuff_wrapper(c_context) 
  fmt.Printf("The return value is %v\n", ret)

}
```

I'd like to get the log value from the callback "back" to the Go code so I can work with it and I'm drawing a blank on how to do that.

Comment: Does [C reference to Go](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go) help?

Comment: @Mark it does and that's the direction I've been going. The problem is that the Go func must have the same method signature that the callback expects. (So no `const char *`). Last night I managed to work around that with a wrapper so the C func calls the exported Go func, but I still can't think how to get information "out" to the `DoCStuff` context (maybe channels?)

Comment: To get the information "out", you could create a GoString in c, and pass that to your exported Go function, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475923/making-a-go-string-in-c-with-cgo). You'd need to be able to control the lifetime and access to the log pointer though. If not, you could allocate your own buffer, strcpy the log to it, then pass the buffer pointer to Go function. Remember to free the buffer afterwards. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39708992/3915).